# Sublime won't show compile errors?

Tags: build, sublimetext3

I've been trying to set up a working environment with sublime. My compiling system works if there are no compile errors, but it does't when there is any. It only says "Build Finished ,1 error" ,no signs for where the error is.

This is my build system.

```
{   
    "cmd"        : ["g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe" ],
    "working_dir":"${file_path}",
    "file_regex": "^(..[^:]*):([0-9]+):?([0-9]+)?:? (.*)$",
    "variants"  :
    [
        {
            "name"  : "Run",
            "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "cmd", "/c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}"]
        },
        {
            "name"  :"RunInCommand",
            "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "g++", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "start", "cmd", "/c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name} && pause"]
        },
        {
            "name"  :"Compile_with_gprof",
            "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "g++","-g","-pg", "${file}", "-o", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "cmd", "/c", "${file_path}/${file_base_name}","&&","gprof ${file_path}/gmon.out > ${file_path}/${file_base_name}.log"]
        }
    ]
}
```

and the commands runs quite well in my cmd

sry for my poor english